# Decoding Attributes in XML using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

So I am trying to bring an XML file into an object in Java. The XML file looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Event>
  <DateCreated>2015-05-14T12:24:17+04:00</DateCreated>
  <StartTime Start="2015-07-21T17:54:00+04:00" Postpone="False" />
  <EventID>12345</EventID>
  <Type>Type A</Type>
  <People>
    <Person ID="1" />
    <Person ID="2" />
  </People>
</Event>
```

I have an Event.java which looks like the following:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Event")
public class Event{
  String DateCreated, Start, Postpone, EventID, EventType;

  @XmlElement(name="DateCreated")
  public void setDateCreated(String DateCreated) {
       this.DateCreated = DateCreated;
  }

  public String getDateCreated() {
      return DateCreated;
  }

  @XmlElement(name="EventID")
  public void setEventID(String EventID) {
       this.EventID = EventID;
  }

  public String getDateCreated() {
      return EventID;
  }
```

etc. My problem occurs when trying to access "Start", "Postpone" (in the StartTime) and the id of the people.

```
  @XmlAttribute(name="Start")
  public void setStartTime(String StartTime) {
        this.Start = StartTime;
  }

  public String getStartTime() {
      return Start;
  }
```

Start never gets set and neither does Postpone which is done in the same manor. From there i'm having similar problems with the ID list which I was going about like this:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="People")
@XmlElement(name="Person")
List<Integer>idList;
```

with no luck. I've tried lots of things with no success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link below can help you [link](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html) . if you have some Xml Attribute , you must specify a java class for the specific out of root xml tag that have this attribute .